# jQuery blur only if mouse is not inside another element

Tags: jquery, blur

Here's what I have:

```
        $('#mini-panel-quick_menu .panel-col-last').mouseout(function(){
            $('#edit-search-block-form--2').blur(function(){
                $('#mini-panel-quick_menu .panel-col-last').removeClass('on');
                $('#mini-panel-quick_menu .panel-col-last').addClass('off');
                $( '#block-search-form' ).removeClass( "open" );
            });
        })
```

I want the blur function to happen but only if your mouse is not inside the ".panel-col-last" element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you probably want [`mouseleave`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=mouseleave) rather than `mouseout`.

`mouseout` fires even if the cursor has moved into a child element, where `mouseleave` only fires when the cursor is entirely outside of your element.

---

You should set a flag that tracks whether the mouse is inside of your element, and check if from the `blur` handler:

```
var mouseIsIn;
$('#mini-panel-quick_menu .panel-col-last').hover(function() {
    mouseIsIn = true;
}, function() {
    mouseIsIn = false;
});

$('#edit-search-block-form--2').blur(function(){
    if (!mouseIsIn) {
        $('#mini-panel-quick_menu .panel-col-last').removeClass('on');
        $('#mini-panel-quick_menu .panel-col-last').addClass('off');
        $( '#block-search-form' ).removeClass( "open" );
    }
});
```

Comment: He probably doesn't want either, as they both require the mouse to enter the element before it will blur on leave or out.

Comment: @TomHeard: By definition, your mouse has to enter an area before it can leave it...

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying. He is wanting to have it blur when it is not inside the element, not when it enters and leaves.

Comment: still doesn't work because I think once you leave the button once that blur function will always fire, even when you mouse back into the ".panel-col-last" element.

Comment: @MattCoady, ah I see now.  Updated.